# Application class data not getting accessed

Tags: android, class, global, android-context

I am definging an application class so that data is available all across java classes, but it is not getting read by them. Any input?

My code is:

```
public class ConApplication extends Application{
private String cookie;

private String globaltoken;

public String getCookie()
{
    return cookie;
}

public void setCookie(String cookie) {
    this.cookie = cookie;

}


public String getglobaltoken()
{
    return globaltoken;
}

public void setglobaltoken(String globaltoken)
{
    this.globaltoken = globaltoken;
}
}
```

The data I am trying to access in a different activity is global token , but it is not getting recognized

```
 context mContext2;
mContext2 = this;

((ConApplication)mContext2.getApplicationContext()).getglobaltoken(globaltoken));
```

Comment: Did you declare this application in Manifest?

Comment: you have declared `getglobaltoken` method without any parameter but trying to pass `globaltoken` when accessing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((Application)mContext2.getApplicationContext()).getglobaltoken(globaltoken));
```

won't do anything by itself!

You'll need to store it to a variable and omit the arg to getglobaltoken:

```
String globalToken = ((Application)mContext2.getApplicationContext()).getglobaltoken());
```

Then you can use it!
However, if no class set the globaltoken, you'll get `null`!

Make sure you have the Application class in your manifest as well:

```
<application android:name="Application">

    <!-- This is where you activities etc. come -->

</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I logged the value of globalToken nothing shows up, looks like the data was not passed at all.

Comment: No logs as such , all I get is 09-26 17:49:27.076: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.x.y.httpcommunicationhelper2/.logout } from pid 330
09-26 17:49:27.546: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.x.y.httpcommunicationhelper2/.logout: +410ms

Answer (score 0):

you should have one application class with extends Application and that name should be specify in manifest with application android:name="pkg_name.app_class_name"